# Create new project in Neo4j programmatically

Tags: database, neo4j, project

Is there anyway to create a new Project and DBMS in Neo4j(desktop) using java or python.

Currently I am creating the Project manually then adding the dbms(multiple)and inside each dbms I am adding multiple databases.